# Linux hangs when listing contents of large external directory

Tags: linux, hard-drive, freeze, lag, files-folders

I have an external NTFS hard drive mounted on my system. This hard drive has a number of top-level directories. Most of them contain nothing of much import, but one contains hundreds of gigabytes of photos, sorted into subdirectories by date.

I can open all directories fine except for the one holding the photos. Opening it with a GUI file browser, or running `ls` while `cd`'d into it in a shell prompt, both hang. `ls` freezes my PC if I let it run too long. `find .` and `ls -U1` output a few filenames (which look correct) but after the first few they just keep printing the same one.

Is this an issue purely due to the directory's size? Do I have a corrupt part of the disk? What's going on here, and how can I access my files?

Comment: you didn't mention what filesystem the external disk uses. it may be relevant

Comment: @JaromandaX Done

Comment: @amshepherd Do you have a (recent) Windows machine that you can use to check the NTFS drive?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm going to try just that once `ddrescue` is done. 18% done and no errors found so far so maybe it's an NTFS weird thing.

Comment: @amshepherd While we're waiting for that, roughly how many files are in the directory? Tens of thousands? Has it ever managed to open the directory?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes on both counts -- tens of thousands (600-800 GB IIRC), and I've opened it before. I seem to recall there was a subdirectory structure by date, _but_ the output of `find .` and `ls -U1` suggests they're in a flat heirarchy, no?

Comment: @amshepherd If it was only in Nautilus that the problem happened, I'd wonder if you were using an old version—[Opening a folder with 10000+ files blocks actions for seconds](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/978)—but as it's not happy even with `ls`, it could well be filesystem corruption, as davidgo suggested in their answer, but of course fsck won't work on an NTFS disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by connecting the drive to a Windows machine as [@AndrewMorton](https://superuser.com/users/272824/andrew-morton) suggested. It told me that the "directory was corrupted or unreadable". I ran a disk check and repair and the problem was solved in less than a minute.

Comment: Phew! It's always good when a simple fix works.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yep. I was sweating bullets for a bit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow! I was also sweating bullets here. I had a problem with the same symptoms (a folder with 1TB of media, suddenly starting to make Nautilus and `ls` to hang; `ls` entirely filling up the RAM and swap memory). Scanned on Windows, found issues, repaired them successfully. All good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This could be a faulty disk and/or a corrupted filesystem.

- First thing I would do is a SMART test.
- Then, if possible a ddrescue on the disk when it is unmounted to image the drive bit-for-bit to another drive (which will in one action create a backup prudent for the next step, indicate if the disk has a hardware problem and do recovery if it does)
- Then I'd try fsck the disk to fix it if its an indexing problem.